# What does make install do when compiling GCC from source code?

Tags: linux, gcc, autoconf

I am trying to compile GCC from source. After `make` finishes, I could not find the GCC binary executable. Here is the configure command I used:

```
../gcc-svn/configure --prefix=/home/user/Documents/mygcc
```

Here are my questions specifically:

1. What should I expect `make install` does?
2. Is `make install` going to do more compilation or just moves some files to `~/Documents/mygcc`? If it is the latter where the GCC executable resides?
3. Any other directory in my system also get affected by `make install`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `--prefix` must be the full PATH : `/home/[name]/Documents/mygcc/` .... Example gcc 7.x : `../gcc-7.1.0/configure --prefix=[PREFIX] --program-suffix=7 --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --disable-libstdcxx-pch` ... The executable´s gcc7, g++7 are installed to [PREFIX]/bin/ . P.S. : Why "svn" ? gcc-7.3 is scheduled  for release tomorrow !

Comment: Thanks. I shortened the path in my post. You are right. I used the full path indeed. I fixed that in my post. so what I am also asking is that whether before `make install` the executable's gcc is made or it would be made after `make install`? Any idea on that?

Comment: What about my libraries (/lib, and etc)? Any other directory other than that specified in `--prefix` also gets affected?

Comment: Run it as non root. You'll see what it attempts to do.

Comment: »» What about my libraries «« : Which libraries ? No specific libraries are mentioned in your question. GCC uses five libraries → Glibc libs: { libm.so.6, libc.so.6 }, and also { libgmp.so.10, libmpfr.so.4, libmpc.so.3 }: if external gmp, mpfr, mpc was used at gcc build. (I always use internal {gmp, mpfr, mpc} for extra gcc builds.) g++ also uses libstdc++.so.6 .

Comment: I meant any system library directory by libraries. Sorry for not clarifying that in advance. I tried what you mentioned and it seems no any other directory gets affected. So all the files and sub-directories are only generated in the ~/Documents/mygcc directory. And I found that the final gcc binary is actually has been made by `make` and is located at `path_to_objdir/gcc/xgcc`. So its name is actaully is `xgcc` not `gcc` before `make install`. Other compilers such as `gfortran` and `g++` are also reside in the same directory. I guess I almost got all the questions I had. Thanks.